# Fast method to write in a TXT file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I made two scripts to make a file and write in it.
The Problem is both are slow (based on Disk Speed)
Is there a better Method to write to a file?

```
let codes = [];
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;

};

for (let i = 0; 1000000 > i; i++)
{
   codes.push(`${makeid(20)}`);
}
fs.writeFile(`./codes/${makeid(5)}.txt`, codes.join('\n'), (err) => {
   if (err)
   {
       message.reply("There was an error processing your request");
       throw err;
   }
}) 
/* Second script */
let stream = fs.createWriteStream(`./codes/${makeid(5)}.txt`);
for (let i = 0; 1000000 > i; i++)
{
   stream.write(`${makeid(20)}`);
}
stream.end();
```

Both Codes take 5-15 seconds.
I'm looking for a faster method to make it in < 5 seconds.
The file is saved in a txt.
Thanks!

Comment: There are several layers of buffering when you write from a programming language. There may be buffering in the I/O library, the operating system buffers, and the disk controller may have its own buffers as well. The library may provide ways to disable its buffering, but there's not too much control of the lower level buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Buffer

Instead of creating an array of strings that you then join, you can create `Buffer`. This is faster because Node.js does not do any conversion, but just writes the bytes in the buffer to the disk.

```
// improved first method

const codes = Buffer.allocUnsafe(1000000 * 20);

for (let i = 0; 1000000 > i; i++) {
  codes.write(`${makeid(20)}`, i * 20, 20);
}

fs.writeFileSync(`./${makeid(5)}.txt`, codes);
```

On my machine this takes 970.012ms instead of 1907.401ms it took before which is **50% less**.

Comment: I tried the Code and it only generated 1 single Code and then 2000000 empty lines

Comment: @Nadelvorhang My bad, forgot the writing offsets. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write data in your text once if you can. So you don't do it on each iteration but after the loop. That way way you do less function calls